# itext - setSimpleColumn unable to understand llx,lly,urx,ury

Tags: java, itext, alignment, pdf-generation

I am developing a simple invoice generation software for my store.
I am trying to print the final things in a PDF using iText but I am not able to work properly with the method setSimpleColumn that I am using with ColumnText.
I am not able to understand the concept of llx,lly,urx,ury but I am trying through hit n try method but not able to get any result
This is my code

```
public class CreateInvoicePdf {
public static final String DEST="C:\\Users\\sanju\\Desktop\\resul.pdf";
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException
{
    File file = new File (DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new CreateInvoicePdf().createPdf(DEST);
}
public void createPdf(String dest) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException
{
    Document d = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    d.open();
    PdfContentByte can = writer.getDirectContent();
    Paragraph companyDetails = new Paragraph("CLIMAX EXCLUSIVE\nShop No. G1 G2 Mohan Bazar\nCentral Market Ashok Vihar\nNew Delhi-110052");
    Paragraph invoiceDetails = new Paragraph("Invoice No : 1234\nDate  :  10/05/2018\nPay : CASH");
    PdfPTable itemTable = new PdfPTable(9);
    itemTable.addCell("1");
    itemTable.addCell("Shirt");
    itemTable.addCell("1999");
    itemTable.addCell("1");
    itemTable.addCell("1999");
    itemTable.addCell("12");
    itemTable.addCell("1500");
    itemTable.addCell("250");
    itemTable.addCell("250");
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(can);
    ct.setSimpleColumn(100,200,300,400);
    ct.addElement(companyDetails);
    ct.go();
    ct.setSimpleColumn(400,200,600,700);
    ct.addElement(invoiceDetails);
    ct.go();
    ct.setSimpleColumn(100, 700, 500, 500);
    ct.addElement(itemTable);
    ct.go();
    d.close();
    writer.close();
}}
```

and the output I am getting is weird.
[image: screenshot OUTPUT PDF attached]

I want the company details and address to be on the upper left corner
The invoice number date and details at upper right corner
The invoice items table below these

Comment: The variable names aren't chosen at random: `llx` = lower-left X coordinate; `lly` = lower-left Y coordinate; `urx` = upper-right X coordinate; `ury` = upper-right Y coordinate. These four values define the two corners of a rectangle (see https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-should-i-interpret-coordinates-rectangle-pdf ). That rectangle defines your column. By the way: why aren't you using iText 7? And why are you creating an invoice in such an awkward way?

Comment: Thankyou for your help
I get the meanings for llx lly urx ury but still i m confused with their usage
The table values i have put just for testing
It will get it values dynamically from a proper invoice software
Any advantages of using iText7 in my case
I am new in programming
Kindly help

Comment: iText 5 is being phased out, including support for iText 5, so if you are new in programming, you should use iText 7 instead of iText 5. Also: you are reinventing the wheel. There is a tutorial on creating invoices with iText on the official web site. Why don't you start with one of the examples, see for instance [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/5-creating-pdf-invoices-basic-profile) or [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml).

Comment: @sanjulgupta in principle you can use either itext variant to create an invoice BUT... If you want to put content at specific positions, you should know that doing so has become easier and more intuitive in itext 7. If you are interested in a library actively developed, itext 7 would be your choice. If you are interested in tagged pdfs/accessibility (PDF/A or PDF/UA), you should also head for itext 7. If you are interested in support by the itext developers and knowledgeable other parties, most of them are more into itext 7 than itext 5 nowadays.